# Does the Eclipse 2019-3 installer require Internet?

Tags: eclipse, installation

We have need to install Eclipse on a network-isolated (on purpose) Windows machine. We can transfer files by USB, so we can physically put the Eclipse installer executable on the machine.

There is already a JDK (1.8) on the machine.

Question is, will just the installer be sufficient? Does it try to "reach out" for additional web resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does require an active connection. If that's not possible, consider one of the packages at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages .